# regular expression to reject non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, replace

why this regex not work? i want to replace my string by all not default charaacters

legal are = a-Za-z0-9- rest should be replaced and return without the forbidden chars

```
  protected string FormatToInvalidChars(string InputString)
    {
        string RegexPattern = @"(^[A-Za-z0-9]*)$";

            string s = Regex.Replace(InputString.Trim(), RegexPattern, "$1");

            return s;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s = Regex.Replace(InputString.Trim(),@"[^A-Za-z0-9]+","");
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be logical. ... now:)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern makes no sense. You're matching only a single-character string that way.

What you want is probably to replace

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]
```

by an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Regex.Replace(InputString.Trim(), @"[^A-Za-z0-9-]", "");
```

(assuming that the hyphen is also legal, as you say in the question)